# Plotting 6 Dimensions in GGPlot Scatter Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to plot 6 dimensions in ggplot on a scatterplot. Is there a limit to the number of dimensions that can be included in a plot? In the following code I am attempting to plot 6 dimensions in ggplot2, however, the variable that I passed to the shape aesthetic is not included in the graph. Is there a way to fix this? Here is the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cp, y=tpr.test.mean, color=minbucket, size=maxcompete, fill = maxdepth, shape = minsplit.cat)) +
  geom_point(pch=21) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "purple")+
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,3.4)) +
  facet_grid(maxcompete.cat ~ maxdepth.cat)+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.25, "cm"))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

And here is the resulting figure. Note that the variable I passed to the shape aesthetic is not included, and the shapes do not vary at all. Is this because the ggplot package limits the number of dimensions in a scatterplot, or is there something I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your `pch = 21` is overriding the shape aesthetic, so I'd remove that. But keep in mind that a plot with four variables mapped to points is already hard to interpret so maybe consider once again whether six is a good idea for the message you want the plot to convey.

Comment: There are some other tricks you can use: you can facet on multiple variables per side, e.g.  `facet_grid(maxcompete.cat + minsplit.cat ~ maxdepth.cat)`. But  a [mcve] would help a lot ...